# Keyboard "App Shortcuts" aren't working in textboxes in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I've assigned "Find..." and "Find" titles to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Chrome and also under All Applications, in Keyboard settings.

However, it doesn't work inside text boxes in Chrome, and I have to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> instead.

The same happens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for example.

It works elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If an app like chrome or Firefox implements custom key handling and doesn’t pass them to the system  that is a design decision the app maker made.  What specifically is your question?

Comment: It works in Chrome, but doesn't work inside textboxes in Chrome. Even the textbox here where I'm typing to you. But when I'm using Ctrl+F somewhere outside the textbox, it does work.

Comment: Chrome would need to enable standard text control within those text boxes for the shortcuts to get processed.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing where to allow copy, paste and undo is the first thing a developer needs to decide. Next is how many undo and if state is saved. Lastly, they have to decide where shortcuts get processed within the app.

- Do they choose to allow undo when you press space to page down and scroll web page content?
- Do they allow search (and/or) replace within a text input field?

These are decisions chrome made on how to handle keyboard input. You might have to open a bug with them if you don’t like or understand how they implemented it. I see this as works as designed even though I (think I) understand your statement here.